# Phone call recording apps only record one side of the conversation

Tags: audio, call-recording

I have a Sony Xperia XA1 running Android 8 and it doesn't matter which phone call recorder I install, it only records one side of the conversation either me or the caller. All the apps do the same on my HTC Desire too.

I'm not sure if it is the app at fault as they all seem to do the same thing, and this didn't start happening until I updated the Android version towards the end of last year.

Does anyone know of a solution to this issue?

Comment: Rooting is the only solution. See my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225753/131553)

Answer (score 0):

in Android, during a call, There is no way to access audio data of call directly. So what most of the app do is they record the audio from your Speaker.
Let me be clear

1. When you speak app directly record your audio with mic, as you are speaking at the higher sound it will be clear enough to be recorded the microphone which is near your mouth.
2. As the App can't access audio calls data so App record audio from your speaker (from where you are listening) and the microphone and speaker has almost distance of 8cm, so if your speaker's volume is high then only app will be able to record audio of the other side's person. Otherwise only your voice will be recorded.

few apps on the playStore provide better phone call recordings but they ask for Root access, if you are really interested in rooting your phone you can follow this article to have some idea "[How to root an Android](https://www.experthoot.com/how-to-root-an-android/)"
Thanks

Comment: this sounds like a design flaw in the Android OS.  Does iOS have this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer is accurate.  I've used Android apps to record calls in the past, and the quality was very good.  I suppose it's possible that they were recording the speaker, but I honestly think it sounded too good for that to be happening.  Note that some brands of Android phones commonly sold in some countries do not have great call audio recording quality, but many of the less common Chinese brands have excellent call recording quality, and even come with call recording apps.

Comment: @beeshyams I just noticed... you may have accidentally deleted your comment to both me and Afflospark.  It was a helpful comment with a link to your answer in the other related QA.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket sure.. All the best. You can always a question, there are lots of competent people! Yes,  I deleted the comment because it isn't correct. I misread the question, it talks of Android 8, while [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225753/131553) talks of Android 9 and beyond. Therefore, the answer is valid for 8, but not correct since call recording works. Anyway linked the answer

Comment: @beeshyams You are invited to chat! https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116758/the-beeshyams-and-the-lizard